# Magnetic ballast replacement

Tags: lighting

Replacing two magnetic ballasts with starters with one electronic ballast that runs two bulbs. Can I leave the starters in place or should I replace the bulb sockets?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bypass the starters electrically.   I leave them in place, saves having to fill the hole.